# Pestphp fails to run tests

Tags: php-pest

I just installed the version 1.21 of pestphp/pest for a small php library.

Installations works until I try running `./vendor/bin/pest`

I keep getting this error: `Exclusive locks are not supported for this stream`

Research on this error has proven unsuccessful as I could not find a similar case.

Please let me know if you've experienced this before and how you fixed it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue.

I was running the application from the htdocs of the vm version of xampp running on my laptop.

Taking the project out of here into another directory solved this issue.

Hope this saves someone else some time.